# Unity www yield return request works in editor but not in fb app

Tags: c#, facebook, unity-game-engine, facebook-unity-sdk

Currently my problem simplified is this:

Code below works in unity editor, I have checked the php multiple times before and now that the url being sent works, and that it returns the correct value, but uploading a build onto the space to be used in the facebook app breaks it for some reason, img provided to show where it stops.

Some other details:

Looking around all signs point to it being a bug with v3.0 (the version I'm working in being v4.3.3f1), but whilst my code below works in the editor no problems, it won't continue past the yield return www request when I upload a build of it onto my html space provided.

The current way the login works before the block below is initialising the FB gameobject, logging into facebook, checking for no errors, then passing back the FB UserID, which is then passed to the code below - of which it works as intended.

Quick edit - DB Connector contains the main url, to which the code below adds on the necessary string for the php get.

I don't know where to begin trying to fix it, save for as shown changing the text being displayed as it progresses, which has helped isolate it down to my question here.

Image of login screen where it sticks: https://i.stack.imgur.com/s9ocX.png

Code:

```
using UnityEngine;

using System.Collections;

using System;

public class ConnectToDataBase : MonoBehaviour {

    public bool bDatabaseConnected = false;
    public bool bConnectionFailed = false;

    public string sFacebookID;
    public WWWForm wwwForm;

    public void vStartConnection()
    {
        var text = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag ("Other");

        text.guiText.text = "Login : connectToDatabase: prepping query";

        //call databasequeries and get sDBConnect
        string sConnectPhp = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("DBConnector").GetComponent<DatabaseQueries>().sDBConnect;

        //now ready the url with the necessary code for php's get, and the FacebookID
        string url = sConnectPhp + "?UserID=" + sFacebookID;

        text.guiText.text = "Login : connectToDatabase: url being sent:\n" + url;

        WWW wwwGet = new WWW(url);

        text.guiText.text = "Login : connectToDatabase: wwwGet created";

        text.guiText.text = "Login : connectToDatabase: starting coroutine";
        StartCoroutine(Connect(wwwGet));
    }

    IEnumerator Connect(WWW www)
    {
        var text = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Other");
        text.guiText.text = "Login : connectToDatabase: coroutine started - sending www request";

        yield return www;

        text.guiText.text = "Login : connectToDatabase: wwwGet yield return";

        string sTemp = www.text;

        if(www.error == null)
        {
            text.guiText.text = "Login : connectToDatabase: wwwGet has not errored";

            string newString = sTemp.ToString();
            int newInt = Convert.ToInt32(newString);

            //print (newString);
            text.guiText.text = "Login : connectToDatabase: checking wwwGet return as int";

            if(newInt == 0)
            {
                //if successfully connected set to true
                print ("connectToDatabase: olduser successful");
                text.guiText.text = "Login : connectToDatabase: olduser successful";

                bDatabaseConnected = true;
                yield break;
            }
            else if(newInt == 1)
            {
                //if successfully connected set to true
                print ("connectToDatabase: newuser successful");
                text.guiText.text = "Login : connectToDatabase: newuser successful";

                bDatabaseConnected = true;
                yield break;
            }
            else if(newInt == 2)
            {
                //game connection has failed
                print ("connectToDatabase: failed");
                text.guiText.text = "Login : connectToDatabase: failed";
                bDatabaseConnected = false;
                bConnectionFailed = true;
                yield break;
            }
            else
            {
                text.guiText.text = "Login : connectToDatabase: php did not return a 0/1/2 value";
            }
        }
        else
        {
            //game connection has failed
            print ("connectToDatabase: failed");
            text.guiText.text = "Login : connectToDatabase: wwwGet has errored:\n" + www.error;

            bDatabaseConnected = false;
            bConnectionFailed = true;
            yield break;
        }

        text.guiText.text = "Login : connectToDatabase: wwwGet if statement skipped entirely";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are different rules when running in browser. As stated [here](https://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/WWW.html) the app is in sand box mode so you need to add a [crossdomain](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/articles/crossdomain_policy_file_spec.html) policy (I know the link is for Flash Player, but the same principles apply).

In the end you need something like this that is saved in **crossdomain.xml** file in the root of your web server.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<cross-domain-policy>
 <allow-access-from domain="*" secure="false"/>
</cross-domain-policy>
```

Comment: Aaah ok thanks, I'll implement it tomorrow when I'm in the labs again.